# Query filtering in PowerBI for Azure Storage

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've been trying to find if we have the option of `Direct Query` available in PowerBI for Azure Storage? The PowerBI I've does show the option of selection between `Import` & `Direct Query` but it doesn't give the option to write any query.

Did some search & found an old post [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Filtering-a-query-limiting-data-using-Power-BI-and-Azure-Table/m-p/588966) that it doesn't have yet.This idea is also formulated on [PowerBI Ideas portal](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/15356262-filter-to-azure-table-storage-from-the-url), but there doesn't seem to have any update yet.

I couldn't find elsewhere whether this is available. Anyone got any updates/ideas?

I wanted to write Spark SQL basically to bring in the data from Azure here. If anyone has done it, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Direct Query is not available on Azure Storage blob/table etc. or flat files, Direct Query is mostly available on data sources that have some compute capacity attached to them to generate the query sent to it from Power BI. For items coming from Azure Storage, it will be import only.
On the Power BI road map is the ability to do direct query on the Power BI services dataflows, how that will work is not known.

If you want to write a Spark SQL query, I would suggest using Azure Databricks, or any other hosted Spark instance that can connect to the Azure Storage, load the data into it, then query from that table when the cluster is running. You can't query/connect to dataframes, you have to save it as a table or view.